# Enable left alt in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, netbeans

I have been using NetBeans for the last 2 years and I got used to using right alt + ctrl for typing symbols like `{`. Now I need to use Alt Gr.

Can I change it or is this just a Visual Studio thing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you are asking to change the keybinds/keyboard shortcuts, you can do that in settings. (Environment => Key Bindings)

[image: Menu]